# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function createUser()

Tags: php, html

Recently I try to make a signup page but there is an error after clicking on submitting button which is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function createUser()
> in C:\xampp2\htdocs\website\includes\signup_incl.php:40 Stack trace:
> #0 {main} thrown.

below are the full coding from the file

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    
    
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $username = $_POST["uid"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
    $pwdrepeat = $_POST["pwdrepeat"];
    
    require_once 'dbh_incl.php';
    require_once 'functions_incl.php';
    
    if (emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) !== false) {
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=emptyinput");
        exit();
    }
    
    if (invalidUid($username) !== false) {
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid");
        exit();
    }
    
    if (invalidEmail($email) !== false) {
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=invalidemail");
        exit();
    }
    
    if (pwdMatch($pwd, $pwdrepeat) !== false) {
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=passworddontmatch");
        exit();
    }
    
    if (uidExists($conn, $username, $email) !== false) {
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=usernametaken");
        exit();
    }
    
    createUser($conn, $name, $email, $username, $pwd);
    
}
else {
    header("location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

Thanks for the help if you guys encounter this :'D

Comment: show code of  `require_once 'dbh_incl.php'` and `require_once 'functions_incl.php'`. Your `createUser()` must be there..

Comment: This means you haven't declare the function yet, your are calling

Comment: It's not clear if the function `createUser()` exists. Is it part of your required files? Please provide the content of the files.

Comment: its okay thank you soo much for helping :D already got it fix :3

Answer (score 0):

The error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function createUser() in C:\xampp2\htdocs\website\includes\signup_incl.php:40 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown.

This means your are calling the function `createUser()` in line **40** of your file `signup_incl.php` which is not existing or can not be found, because it is not defined.